# What character creation tools & guides are available for Shadowrun 5e?

Tags: character-creation, shadowrun-sr5, tool-recommendation

I'm a totally new player to Shadowrun 5e. My experiences are largely with D&D 4e, Savage Worlds, and Cyberpunk 2020. I'm just seeing if there are any unofficial (but very helpful) guides or tools to creating and managing Shadowrun 5e characters. I've been able to find a bunch for 4e, but not for 5e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a Fillable Form [PDF character sheet](http://www.bradkelley.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/SR5-Character-Sheet-Form-20120717.pdf) for 5e that should be helpful in updating and creating my character. I will continue to look and update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice resource, but it's worth noting that characters with a high magic priority will likely not have enough space on that sheet to record all of their spells. I believe an A priority Magician gets 10 spells at character creation and there's only 8 lines on the sheet. The official printed sheets have the same problem but it's more easily remedied by writing on the back / in the margins.

Answer (score 8):

Yours truly has created a variety of form fillable character sheets:

"Dumb" sheet (which only has fillable forms): [Here](http://blog.homoeoteleuton.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/KylesFormFillableSR5Sheet.pdf)

"V2" sheet (has some calculation capability): [Here](http://blog.homoeoteleuton.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ShadowrunFormFillableCS2.pdf)

"V2.5" sheet (extended to a third page, more calculations): [Here](http://blog.homoeoteleuton.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ShadowrunFormFillableCS25a.pdf)

Note that 2.5 is somewhat obtuse to use; in V2.5, the modified attributes on the first page feed from modifiers given on the third page; however, 2.5 is by far the most complex SR5 character sheet I've seen out there in terms of what it can do. I've got some more versions up on [my site](http://blog.homoeoteleuton.com/?page_id=983) as well, though for the most part what you see here is what the "best" is, depending on whether you want pure traditional, traditional+calculations, or traditional+expanded+calculations.

Comment: For the time being I think this is the most comprehensive option as the only alternative is forums with people's very subjective opinions about builds.

Answer (score 6):

I created a [SR5 character sheet editable and a shadowrunner's creation summary](http://www.archaos-jdr.fr/shadowrun5/index.php?page=SR5-personnages).

The character sheet is a 2 pages sheet with all the skills. It looks like the character sheet for Shadowrun 4 I wrote.

The summary contains all the steps for character creation with the errata preview (lifestyle cost and mystical adept).

Comment: My personal favorite, even more so than my own, particularly when you include the character creation summary.

Comment: I updated my first comment to explain the content. It's OK ?

Answer (score 4):

### The Omae SR5 Character Generator

Omae is a javascript-based character creator that supports the priority system of SR5. It's not finished, however, but it will make sure that you get a valid and legal result under the standard ruleset of SR5.

Features include adept power and spell selection, a limited gear selection (much of this will have to be done by hand afterward), full skill advancement and selection, and accounting for skill groups, though as of November 5th it lacks full support for Technomancers, the standard gear list, qualities, and additional karma spending during character creation.

[Link to Omae](https://heyomae.github.io/)

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work in IE11. Use Chrome or Firefox (they've been tested with it).

Comment: Are you the developer? Can I make some suggestions? In the chat room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12137/sr5-omae-char-builder

Comment: Nope. I don't remember who made it, but I found it on one of the forums.

Comment: @KyleWilley Omae is made by a user called [dethstrobe](https://www.reddit.com/user/dethstrobe).

Answer (score 3):

As a side note: for a new player, SR 4e is preferable, due to superior supplement coverage.

You may want to check out [Chummer](https://code.google.com/p/chummer5/), it was recently forked to a 5e version.

There also is a few 5e spreadsheets, for example, [here](http://forums.shadowruntabletop.com/index.php?topic=11723.0).

Comment: I did see the Chummer page, Hopefully there is a 5e version. The 2 guys (1 of them here on SE) that have talked to me about being in a SR game are both talking about sr5 so I'm locked into it in that sense.

Comment: Your earlier statement about 4e being preferable is somewhat subjective; more supplements may not help a new player, and 5e's a lot more streamlined.

Comment: It is, and I can elaborate on that, but it would be hard not to devolve to edition war, IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately the Chummer author stopped the progress of porting it to SR5: http://forums.dumpshock.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=36737&view=findpost&p=1243343

Comment: @JoachimSauer he released the source codes, so someone might continue the work.

Comment: @JeorMattan: that's true, but from experience, the chances are low: a one-man-project with the original author effectively gone is *really hard* for another developer to take over. And starting anew is just more fun, so many people (including me) will do that (which, of course, will take longer to produce a useable result).

Comment: I fully agree with Joachim and Kyle. SR4 is not more recommended for new players exactly because SR5 is more streamlined and does not yet have dozens of bonus rules that are more or less mandatory. Also, I seriously doubt anyone will pick up Chummer, because of the reasons Joachim mentioned. So far, nobody has.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind paying for it ($30 for new users), Hero Lab [just added SR5 support](http://forums.wolflair.com/showthread.php?t=49426) a few days ago. I haven't tried it yet, but I used Hero Lab with SR4, and it was better than the free options available at the time, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Around February of 2015 the chummer5 code was cloned and is under fairly active development. **The software is now titled [chummer5a](https://github.com/chummer5a/chummer5a/releases)** and seems like a fairly comprehensive choice, having tons of (extensible and updatable) source data and multiple export options for simple data output to full sheets.

No, I am not affiliated.

Answer (score 1):

**My preferred option is [Hero Lab](http://www.wolflair.com/index.php?context=hero_lab).** It's easy to use, gives you plenty of options, and gets frequent updates to fix bugs or add more content. Despite not being free, I personally find that Hero Lab is worth it for SR5, just because there is so much material that it's hard to keep your math straight with other tools or methods. I find that form-fillable character sheets for SR5 in particular simply don't adequately do the job because either they never have enough room for all the information I need to be able to reference quickly or they aren't flexible enough to accommodate a system with as many bells-and-whistles as SR5. There is just no substitute for having a licensed product that can include the entire long-form description of a particular item or ability without running afoul of copyright issues.

It's also worth noting that as of the writing of this answer [Hero Lab has all of the currently published supplemental material](http://www.wolflair.com/index.php?context=hero_lab&page=shadowrun_packages) available (including errata) with the exception of *Run Faster*, which just came out recently (within the last month). The down side is that to get all of this content (assuming you don't already have a Hero Lab license) requires a steep $60 investment ($30 for the software itself, and then $10 for each of the three data packs which add the supplemental content). If you play SR5 frequently, especially with all of the currently published supplements, it's invaluable as it essentially does all the work for you. If you don't play very often, you're probably better off with a free open-source option like [Omae](https://heyomae.github.io/) or [Chummer5](https://code.google.com/p/chummer5/).

Answer (score 0):

Chummer5a is updated quite often and has a lot of nightly builds and just as easy if not easier than Hero Lab