# What are the most important features needed in a shadowrun 5E character generator?

Tags: character-creation, tools, shadowrun-sr5, character-sheets

I am working on a character generator for sr5. I need to know what feature has been most neglected in a shadowrun character generator. Something which I can implement which would set the character generator apart and make it more useful to GMs and Players alike.

What is this one missing feature?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about development of RPG tools and not about the RPG itself.

Comment: @MadMAxJr I think this question might be salvageable, as tools for running RPGs are on-topic even though development isn't; it just needs rephrasing.  Welcome to the site, Demonnic.  We'll be better able to give you a meaningful answer if you can edit to be more specific about what you're looking for, in roleplay terms.  (Do you want a feature list from players about what's important in character creation?  A wish-list for GM automatic NPC creation?   You'll need to let us know what would constitute a "correct" answer; we don't cover general discussion here.)

Comment: Voting to close. There are character creation related things that would tell people what they need to have; look for the character creation guide here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/27899/3136

Comment: Ok first...Welcome to the site! Have a look at the FAQ and don't worry we don't bite. Your question would require a list and RPG.Stackexchange is not fond of lists so whenever you get 20 reputations feel free to pop in the chat.

Comment: I don't believe the question about what is already available actually answers what I am looking for. I'm really looking for what one feature has been lacking which people are looking for. Basic things such as 'rules correctness' I think go without saying. I have tried to rephrase the question to make it more specific and more in line with the information on the FAQ. If further refinement would help, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it stands, the question either requires a market survey or is purely opinion based.